# Expected Value of an inefficient estimator of the $\beta$ parameter of a simple linear regression

Tags: probability, statistics, regression

A simple linear regression is defined as follow: 
$$y_i=\alpha+\beta x_i+\epsilon_i \qquad i=1,...,n$$

An inefficient way of estimating $\beta$ is defined as follow:
$$\tilde{\beta}=\frac{\overline{y}''-\overline{y}'}{\overline{x}''-\overline{x}'}$$
where $\overline{y}'$ is the average of the **first** three observations, while $\overline{y}''$ is the average of the **last** three observations. The same logic is applied to $\overline{x}'$ and $\overline{x}''$.

I think I can write them in this way (but I'm not really sure if this can simplify the resolution of the problem):
$$\overline{y}'=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^3 y_i$$
$$\overline{y}''=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=n-2}^n y_i$$
$$\overline{x}'=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i$$
$$\overline{x}''=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=n-2}^n x_i$$

How can I find a way to prove that $\tilde\beta$ is an unbiased estimator of $\beta$? Or, in mathematical terms, how can I compute this:
$$E[\tilde{\beta}]=\beta$$

Comment: $E[\tilde\beta]=\beta$ means the estimator is unbiased, not the same thing as consistency.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the right solution. Since $x_i$’s are known I can do the following: $$E[\tilde\beta]=\frac{1}{\overline{x}''-\overline{x}'}E[\overline{y}''-\overline{y}']$$ Where: $$E[\overline{y}'']=\frac{1}{3}\sum\underset{=a+bx_i}{\underbrace{E[y_i]}}=\frac{1}{3}\left ( \sum a + b\sum x_i \right )=\frac{1}{3}3a+b\frac{1}{3}\sum x_i=a + b \overline{x}'’$$ $$E[\overline{y}’]=…=a + b \overline{x}’$$ So: $$E[\tilde\beta]=...=\frac{1}{\overline{x}''-\overline{x}'}\underset{=b\overline{x}''-b\overline{x}'}{\underbrace{\left ( a+b \overline{x}'' - a - \overline{x}' \right )}}=\frac{1}{\overline{x}''-\overline{x}'}b(\overline{x}''-\overline{x}')=b$$

Answer (score 0):

First a small point the sum is from n-2 to n.  Write $y_i=\alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$ You have $E[\epsilon_i]=0$  . Plug these two formulae in and the result drops out.